# Flow: choosing between actions in the reducer

Tags: redux, flowtype

**TLDR:** I have modeled my problem in Try Flow ([link](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAYgeQTAvDA5Ih6BQpKwBCAggEqoYmm45QCeADgKYzHBQCW4A6h1ABYBRMJ05MIFAN4AfHDBj1mALhjQAThzABzADRyYDAIZ0ANiEMATFTP3ymIvh3HXZ8tzD5MAthGu33MADa6ppaALoqIdr+8gC+-tLx8ok4KbSMLGycPHz8cCAgUq4KGSqKTCAAZvBIevJGpuZWMDbulQWRUBrRyfFp5azsXGC8AoSGakX65WUZVTBUdQbGZpYu-gBGE53dWvop-RmD2WCo+8fDo0IOYhDnWZe5+SD3QzljEzjpzDAAylCGKAsNCSeI4SoAVzAb1OaiYFghwCYagAFNBAUwVP8MToYIYYSoHuAAJQtfQcaoo-EnAB0DVWFhgADImXiYXSVk0afZRE4JCy2bT6VyeY5xDTPD5SZJ-HCoBC1KcEBsAFZMdg0wwQCAcLRgFGg3HooG46nDDmNSzcm58iVAqUAbn0YPkEAA7nxgPwqezytL-MAtSwsEocABIeT4aAwdqFNBm8AWhk02NOgIwOUK06SGMFGBJNyBiAsKh+dNR2BbSbx9nCq1VtMBTOKlowKv5-wF+QWJiVQwQkxQUPp5unY1MRvxWJAA)). Could you please help me solve it?

**Full description of the problem:**

In a Redux reducer, I am choosing between three actions. One action can have any type, but its distinctive feature is that it has a specific field in its payload (`payload.entities.items` in this example). Two other actions have specific types to tell them apart, and also have different payloads:

```
const FOO = 'FOO'
const BAR = 'BAR'

type ActionWithEntities = {|
  type: string,
  payload: {|
    entities: {|
      items: {
        [string]: string
      }
    |}
  |}
|}

type ActionWithFoo = {|
  type: typeof FOO,
  payload: {|
    foo: string
  |}
|}

type ActionWithBar = {|
  type: typeof BAR,
  payload: {|
    bar: string
  |}
|}

type Action =
  | ActionWithEntities
  | ActionWithFoo
  | ActionWithBar
```

Depending on the action, I want to do whatever appropriate (doesn't really matter what) in the reducer:

```
function reducer(state: State, action: Action) {
  if (action.payload && action.payload.entities && action.payload.entities.items) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload.entities.items);
  }

  switch(action.type) {
    case FOO:
      const foo = action.payload.foo;
      return { foo }
    case BAR: {
      const bar = action.payload.bar;
      return { bar }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My problem is, Flow doesn't see that the if-statement takes care of the first action (because other actions don't have the `entities` field in their payload), and complains inside the switch statement that the field that I am trying to use (`foo` or `bar` in this example) is absent from the first action.

What’s the correct way to make Flow happy?

Answer (score 3):

The reason flow doesn't like this is because ActionWithEntities's type field is of type string, which means it could have value FOO or BAR. Now, your logic would prevent it from hitting the switch/case, but flow is not able to follow that logic and refine the type. One way to resolve it would be to explicitly type the type field for ActionWithEntities

So something like

```
type ActionWithEntities = {|
  type: 'OTHER' | 'OTHER2' | 'OTHER3',
  payload: {|
    entities: {|
      items: {
        [string]: string
      }
    |}
  |}
|}
```

Comment: That’s unfortunate. I thought Flow was able to refine types when given a set of explicit if-statements. Do you know whether Flow has a way of excluding a certain set of strings from the string type, so that I do not need to enumerate all possible strings in the `type` field, but instead say that this field is a string that is neither FOO nor BAR?

Comment: @azangru: I don't think you can exclude some strings from the `string` type. It wouldn't be possible to statically typecheck.